# I have a parameterless public constructor but I am still getting an error saying I need one

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The error is:

> An error occurred while creating a
>   controller of type 'foo'. If the
>   controller doesn't have a controller
>   factory, ensure that it has a
>   parameterless public constructor.

However, fooController has a parameterless public constructor.  I'm using the default factory.  As far as I know, this code was working, and nothing has changed - I did install, then uninstall, MVC2.

Comment: Please post the controller code.

Comment: Please provide more details about the code. If you can show your controller's declaration and constructor that would help.

Comment: Please also include the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you get this error if there's an exception throw in the constructor.  Technically, the error message is correct, but the extra information is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the constructor is both public and parameterless. Also check that the controller's type name ends with "Controller".